# Does servicing an API from a subdomain make your app slower?

Tags: subdomain, web-applications, api

I have a single-page application (SPA) located in `application.com`, and I want to serve the API from `api.application.com`.

Since this is a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) browser application, it will always make `OPTIONS` requests prior to the actual one. Would this make my SPA twice as slow?

Comment: Benchmark it and see. (And find out the answer is no. That little bit of extra work shouldn't have that kind of effect on your load times).

Answer (score 2):

Since your OPTIONS response doesn't actually rely on the same application logic your application does I wouldn't expect it to be twice as slow. If your OPTIONS response does not include an entity-body (only a header response, similar to HEAD) then the data transfer will be quite small and much quicker. But you will still have the latency between your visitor/user and your application server.

Also, I would go with a DNS A record for your sub domain, if not already. If you use a CNAME record it will require an additional DNS lookup to get the IP address for what the CNAME entry is pointed at.